# Run Jquery script after loading html file with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

These are the codes I have:

The index file:

```
<div class="other">other images</div>

<div class="fotos">
<?php include ('images.html'); ?>
</div>
```

The main jQuery:

```
$('.other').click (function(){
$('.fotos').load('otherimages.html');
$.getScript("javascript/center.js");
});
```

images.html :

```
<img src="image1.jpg"></img>
<img src="image2.jpg"></img>
<img src="image3.jpg"></img>
<img src="image4.jpg"></img>
<img src="image5.jpg"></img>
```

The problem is: The script "center.js" has to run AFTER all the images are loaded.
Can anyone help?

thanx, gr Tim

Comment: put it below all your code.i.e.add script in the last.have you got any error on the console.

Comment: Kindly Load it before page load
$('.other').click (function(){
$.getScript("javascript/center.js");
$('.fotos').load('otherimages.html');

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a callback to [`jQuery.fn.load(url[, data][, complate])`](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('.other').click (function() {
    $('.fotos').load('otherimages.html', function() {
        $.getScript("javascript/center.js");
    });
});
```